# Mxnet with symbol API: batch normalization update

Tags: c++, mxnet

I am currently training a convolutional neural network using Mxnet, with the C++ Symbol API. This network contains some Batchnormalization layers, which contains the four parameter NDArray. Two of them, the moving_mean and moving_variance parameter are supposed to be updated at every batch during the training.

I was guessing that, since the boolean for the forward pass of the executor is set to `true`, it would update automatically the new parameters. However, for some reasons, these two NDArray remains still, without any update of the parameter.  How so? Besides, since there are no gradients computed for these two NDArray, because it is not "learnable" parameters, I have no way to update the values through the regular optimizer update function. How to tell Mxnet, using the symbol API, to update the moving_mean and moving_variance NDArrays?

Answer (score 0):

`moving_mean` and `moving_variance` are updated during the backward pass of training, rather than during the optimization step like other parameters. One other reason these parameters could remain fixed during training is if you've set `use_global_stats=True` on the BatchNorm layer.